# Does IItemsRangeInfo support CollectionViewSource?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

I want to use IItemsRangeInfo with grouped data.

```
public class GroupSource:ObservableCollection<GroupSourceItem>, IItemsRangeInfo
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void RangesChanged(ItemIndexRange visibleRange, IReadOnlyList<ItemIndexRange> trackedItems)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionSource}}" 

CollectionSource.Source = new GroupSource(){....};
```

I tried this, but there is not event when I scroll the view. I don't know if IItemsRangeInfo support CollectionViewSource or maybe there is something wrong in my code.

Comment: What's the purpose of using CollectionSource? Can you try directly binding the GridView's ItemsSource property to the GroupSource?

Comment: @Jackie I want to group my data. Just Like what Photos did in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does IItemsRangeInfo support CollectionViewSource?

The answer is no.

The problem is CollectionViewSource does not implement IItemsRangeInfo interface, so that the "RangesChanged" event won't be routed from CollectionViewSource to the GroupSource.

Comment: Thanks! So how can I implement “Random access data virtualization” mentioned here ： [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt574120.aspx)

Comment: Because CollectionViewSource does not implement IItemsRangeInfo, you'll need to directly bind the ItemsSource to the GroupSource. Next step  you can take is to add a Converter for grouping/sorting the data.